# Well posed or ill posed inverse problem?

Tags: inverse-problems

Consider the problem of finding a control parameter $p(t)$ in the following
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+p(t)u(x,t)+f(x,t),  
\ ~~\  0\leq x \leq1 ,\ ~~\ 0< t \leq1
\end{equation}
with the initial conditions
\begin{equation}
\  u(x,0)=h(x), \ ~~\  0\leq x \leq1
\end{equation}
and boundary conditions
\begin{equation}
\  u(0,t)=g_1(x), \ ~~\  0< t \leq1
\\  u(1,t)=g_2(x), \ ~~\  0< t \leq1
\end{equation}
with an additional condition which describes the overspecification over a portion of spatial domain
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{s(t)} u(x,t) dx = E(t),  \ ~~\  0< t \leq1,   \ ~~\  0< s(t) \leq1
\end{equation}

I know the existence and uniqueness of the solution but I don't have any idea whether it is stable or not. Please help me out with the stability of the solution.

Comment: You probably have a type in the boundary conditions; currently, $g_1(x) = u(0,t) = g_2(x) $.